# Optimizing Join, GroupBy, Distinct, Min/Max on naturally sorted sequences

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-objects

LINQ operators operate on the assumption that input sequences are not sorted, which is great for generic cases. However, the above operators could be more efficient if source sequences were sorted on the key values.

For example, Join reads whole inner sequence into a hash table and only then iterates over outer sequence. If two sequences were sorted, Join could be implemented as a simple merge with no additional storage and hash table lookups.

Is there a library that has alternative high-performance LINQ functions operating on pre-sorted sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop [Nito.LINQ](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/) as I have time. It provides `ISortedEnumerable` and `ISortedList` with some of the optimizations you suggest. I also include more controversial optimizations (e.g., `Skip` for `IList`, which slightly changes the semantics).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not for LINQ to Objects.  Most LINQ providers which work on `IQueryable<T>` already do a translation to a "native" function that could easily have this type of optimization in place.  For example, when working with Entity Framework, the EF provider will turn this into a SQL call, and the DB (hopefully) will optimize this correctly.

LINQ to Objects is a bit different, though.  There, most of the routines (including all of the above) are designed to work with unsorted data, and even different implementations of  `IEqualityComparer<T>` or `IComparer<T>`.  This would mean that an "optimized" version would not only work on only a small set of potential data, but only be optimized for a subset of the standard query operations.

That being said, it'd be fairly easy to do this using your own wrappers around the standard LINQ operations, for those specific cases.  You would need a way to know, in advance, that the collection in question was sorted, however, which would probably require your own separate interface (or a runtime check, such as the `Count()` optimizations done on `ICollection`).

Comment: As an aside, there is the `IOrderedByEnumerable<>` interface which expresses when a sequence is already available in some order. Unfortunately, it doesn't express which facet of the object is being used for ordering, it's primarily provided to make it possible for the language to constrain when LINQ operators like `ThenBy()` make sense. It may be possible to use this interface as a starting point for creating certain optimized versions of operators like Join - but it would still require some knowledge from the developer to use them appropriately.

Comment: If I am to code it from scratch I would probably started by overloading standard operators to work on IKeyOrdered<K,T>:IEnumerable<T> { K Key; ...}

Answer (score 0):

As Reed mentions, it would be very difficult to discover what the sequence was sorted by in order to determine whether an optimisation would work. You don't really want to have to roll duplicate collection classes, or tie yourself to specific implementations (like `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`), to write overrides of the LINQ extension methods.

So, what about just adding some new operators, or overloads, where you as the consumer provide a guarantee that the data is ordered. These can still be extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` and would not be guaranteed to succeed unless the collection was ordered.

An example would be `OrderedJoin`, where you'd have to provide an `IComparable<TKey>` in order to know which squence to advance next if the current item in each sequence doesn't have a match on the key. Here's the signature as a starter. You can let us know when you've implemented your whole library!

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OrderedJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector,
    IComparable<TKey> comparer
)
```

Comment: Indeed. This would be a similar philosophy to the built-in `BinarySearch` methods on `List<T>` and `Array`. They assume that they're acting on a sorted list/array. There's nothing to enforce that contract programmatically, but if you don't stick to it then you're going to get useless results.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace OrderedJoin
{
    public static class EnumerableExtension
    {
        private enum JoinType
        {
            Inner,
            Left,
            Right,
            Full
        }

        private static IEnumerable<TResult> OrderedJoinIterator<T, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right, Func<T, T, TResult> resultSelector, JoinType jt, IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("left");
            if (right == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("right");
            if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");

            if (comparer == null)
                comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

            var l = left.GetEnumerator();
            var r = right.GetEnumerator();

            var lHasData = l.MoveNext();
            var rHasData = r.MoveNext();

            while (lHasData || rHasData)
            {
                if (!lHasData && rHasData)
                {
                    if (jt == JoinType.Inner || jt == JoinType.Left)
                        yield break;
                    yield return resultSelector(default(T), r.Current);
                    rHasData = r.MoveNext();
                    continue;
                }
                if (!rHasData && lHasData)
                {
                    if (jt == JoinType.Inner || jt == JoinType.Right)
                        yield break;
                    yield return resultSelector(l.Current, default(T));
                    lHasData = l.MoveNext();
                    continue;
                }

                var comp = comparer.Compare(l.Current, r.Current);

                if (comp < 0)
                {
                    if (jt == JoinType.Left || jt == JoinType.Full)
                        yield return resultSelector(l.Current, default(T));
                    lHasData = l.MoveNext();
                }
                else if (comp > 0)
                {
                    if (jt == JoinType.Right || jt == JoinType.Full)
                        yield return resultSelector(default(T), r.Current);
                    rHasData = r.MoveNext();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return resultSelector(l.Current, r.Current);
                    lHasData = l.MoveNext();
                    rHasData = r.MoveNext();
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> OrderedInnerJoin<T, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right, Func<T, T, TResult> resultSelector, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            return OrderedJoinIterator(left, right, resultSelector, JoinType.Inner, comparer);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> OrderedFullJoin<T, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right, Func<T, T, TResult> resultSelector, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            return OrderedJoinIterator(left, right, resultSelector, JoinType.Full, comparer);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> OrderedLeftJoin<T, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right, Func<T, T, TResult> resultSelector, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            return OrderedJoinIterator(left, right, resultSelector, JoinType.Left, comparer);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> OrderedRightJoin<T, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right, Func<T, T, TResult> resultSelector, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            return OrderedJoinIterator(left, right, resultSelector, JoinType.Right, comparer);
        }
    }

    internal class TestEnum : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        public TestEnum(string name, IList<int> nums)
        {
            Name = name;
            Nums = nums;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public IList<int> Nums { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var item in Nums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Name, item);
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var e1 = new TestEnum("L", new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 6 });
            var e2 = new TestEnum("R", new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 6 });

            var print = new Action<IEnumerable<string>>(seq => { foreach (var item in seq) Console.WriteLine("\t" + item); });

            Console.WriteLine("Standard Inner Join:");
            print(e1.Join(e2, i => i, j => j, (i, j) => string.Format("{0} <=> {1}", i, j), EqualityComparer<int>.Default));

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered Inner Join:");
            print(e1.OrderedInnerJoin(e2, (i, j) => string.Format("{0} <=> {1}", i, j)));

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered Full Join:");
            print(e1.OrderedFullJoin(e2, (i, j) => string.Format("{0} <=> {1}", i, j)));

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered Left Join:");
            print(e1.OrderedLeftJoin(e2, (i, j) => string.Format("{0} <=> {1}", i, j)));

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered Right Join:");
            print(e1.OrderedRightJoin(e2, (i, j) => string.Format("{0} <=> {1}", i, j)));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```